# Term for array of identical type and different types

Tags: terminology, arrays

What is proper terminology to distinguish between an array (ordered list) data structure in which each element is of identical type/class, and an array in which each element can be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A structure containing only the same type is homogeneous, and a structure containing different types is heterogeneous.